# Add predefined/default values to custom post plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, post-content

I have created a custom post plugin.

I need to add predefined text/values within this plugin, when adding new custom post.

Is it possible to handle these predefined text/values in my plugin PHP file, and make them active?

```
/*
Plugin Name: Grand Prix Autíčka
Plugin URI: http://www/
Description: Přidávání autíček
Version: 1.0
Author: Thomas Dobo
Author URI: http://www/
License: GPLv2
*/

add_action( 'init', 'create_movie_review' );

function create_movie_review() {
    register_post_type('movie_reviews', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Grand Prix Autíčka',
            'singular_name' => 'Movie Review',
            'add_new' => 'Přidat Nový',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Movie Review',
            'edit' => 'Upravit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Movie Review',
            'new_item' => 'New Movie Review',
            'view' => 'View',
            'view_item' => 'View Movie Review',
            'search_items' => 'Search Movie Reviews',
            'not_found' => 'No Movie Reviews found',
            'not_found_in_trash' =>
            'No Movie Reviews found in Trash',
            'parent' => 'Parent Movie Review'
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 15,
        'supports' =>
        array('title', 'editor', 'comments',
            'thumbnail',),
        'taxonomies' => array(''),
        'menu_icon' =>
        plugins_url('images/image.png', __FILE__),
        'has_archive' => true
            )
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_admin' );
```

i add this code but does not works **I need default content only for plugins new post**

```
function my_editor_content( $content ) {
    $content = "";    
    if ( 'movie_reviews' == get_post_type() ) {
        $content = "This is some custom content I'm adding to the post editor because I hate re-typing it."; 
    }

    return $content;
}
```

please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`default_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/default_content/) filter which filter the default post content on add new post screen only.

Example:

```
function filter_function_name( $content, $post ) {
    if ( 'movie_reviews' == get_post_type($post) && empty($content) ) {
        $content = "This is some custom content I'm adding to the post editor because I hate re-typing it.";
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'default_content', 'filter_function_name', 10, 2 );
```